# CLion gives 'expression expected' when using a macro in comparison

Tags: c, clion, preprocessor

I have the following code:

```c
for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_INSTRUCTIONS; i++){
        if (strcmp(word, instructions[i]) == 0){
            if ((i == DATA) || (i == STRING) || (i == MAT)){
                return TRUE;
            }
            else{
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
```

and DATA, STRING and MAT are defined in another file that is included in the file that contains this code:

```c
#define DATA  0
#define STRING  1
#define MAT  2
#define ENTRY  3
#define EXTERN  4
```

For some reason CLion gives me: 'Expression expected' error after each of the comparisons. 
Is there something wrong with my code?

Note: C-Lion is set to work with C-89 specification.

Comment: probably is not included. wrap it in (the whole thing) in `#ifdef DATA ... #endif` if it compiles that means that DATA is not defined

Comment: Please show the full code and the **exact** errors. Also, where is `NUM_OF_INSTRUCTIONS`, `TRUE` and `FALSE` defined?

Comment: It this a compile error or something the IDE is telling you in a tooltip or something? Please put together a short complete example of the problem. I can take your code and make it compile, but there are far too many blanks to fill in to do so.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - It is a tooltip given by the IDE. I will finish other parts in the code and check if the compiler also gives this error.

Comment: @DebanikDawn - Everything in this code is defined in the same header file, this is why I find this behavior odd, since I don't get errors in the other macros in this code.

Comment: @PeterJ - It is wrapped with ifndef, so this is not the problem. Also, when something is not defined, CLion gives a different error.

Comment: What is the exact error? Please show that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - it was a stupid mistake by me. somewhere down the code (outside the scope of the loop) there was an else block that contained only a TODO note but no actual code. This fixed the problem. Luckily, the compiler gave that correct location of the error, while CLion didn't.
Thanks a lot to everyone who answered.